# Integration of $e^{p(x)}$, for some polynomial $p(x)$

Tags: integration, polynomials

What is the indefinite integration of $e^{p(x)}$, for some polynomial $p(x)$? The polynomial can be considered as:
$$p(x)=p_0 +p_1x+p_2x^2+...+p_nx^n$$

Comment: There is none. A few special cases are possible in terms of special functions

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form? For instance, take $p(x) = x^2$. There's no closed form for $e^{x^2}$. Though this has a power series representation.

Comment: There is none even with special functions....but this may interest you : http://goo.gl/s3pQIl

Answer (score 2):

If the polynomial is of degree less or equal to $2$, there are closed forms for the integral but the result involves the error function which is not the most trivial.

To get it, the idea is to complete the square $$p_2x^2+p_1x+p_0=p_2\Big(\big(x+\frac{p_1}{2p_2}\big)^2-\frac{p_1^2-4p_0p_2}{4p_2^2}\Big)$$ and to make appropriate change of veriable to have an integrand looking as $e^{-y^2}$ which leads to the error functions.

As a result, you would have $$\int e^{p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }  }{2 \sqrt{p_2}}e^{p_0-\frac{p_1^2}{4 p_2}}\text{erfi}\left(\frac{p_1+2 p_2 x}{2
   \sqrt{p_2}}\right)$$

The other solution, which would be an approximation, would consist in a Taylor expansion of the integrand followed by an integration of each term as shown by NeilRoy.